# Delete entire object in json matching specific value

Tags: json, ansible

I need to update/edit a json formatted file.

So, I want to delete a entire object, where the name has specific value.

Here, the value is of the type 
"name": "value1_1:value1_2"

Here, value1_1 is the specific value which I am looking for.

If any object matches value1_1, I wish to delete the entire object.

Is it possible to accomplish this using ansible or does it need any custom changes ?

For example: Here I want to delete first object where the value is value1_1.

```js
{
  "objects": [
    {
     "name": "value1_1:value1_2"
    },

    {
     "name": "value2_1:value2_2"
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON-editing task is trivial using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), so let me first
point to a web page about  using jq with Ansible:

https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/ansible-and-jq-9d8e50ec3379

With that out of the way, here is the jq filter for filtering out
objects with .name beginning with "value1_1:" :

```
.objects |= map(select(.name|startswith("value1_1:")|not))
```

Please note that generally speaking, jq expects its input to be valid JSON.
You can check whether this is the case by running `jq empty input.json` at the console
prompt.  If your input is not sufficiently valid JSON, see the jq FAQ for suggestions:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json

If the example snippet is typical, you could, for example, rectify the pseudo-JSON by running:

```
hjson -j snippet.txt
```